# Accessing a specific file in zipped folder using perl (perl module)

Tags: perl, php-ziparchive

I am trying to access a text file **within a zipped folder** to extract a certain information, without actually unzipping the file. I am trying to use Archive::Zip. The directory structure is like Data_stats.zip--> Data_stats/ --> full_data_stats.txt. Now I tried this

```
use Archive::Zip;
use Archive::Zip::MemberRead;
use File::Basename;

$zip_dir=$ARGV[0];
@name =split("\\.",basename($zip_dir)); ## to get zipped folder name
$dir = Archive::Zip->new("$zip_dir");
$fh = Archive::Zip::MemberRead->new($dir,"$name[0]/full_data_stats.txt"); ##trying to reads the file giving the path and mentioning the specific file name

while (defined($line = $fh->getline()))
{
{print}
}
```

I see it extracting the folder but not reading in the file !!.

Regards

Comment: YOU are fabulous !!...such a silly mistake on my part :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning to $line but printing $_; try `print $line;`